# Uncaught SyntaxError Multiple Appends

Tags: jquery, append

I have having problems appending more then one object to a UL list. The error shows on line 68 which is separately commented out

*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <* Bellow

> `<li data-role="list-divider">' + obj.storename + '</li>`
>   Error

**Javascript**

```
    $('.data').append(

    '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li data-role="list-divider">' + obj.storename + '</li>
       <li>' + obj.notes + '</li>
       <li>' + obj.rejected + '</li>
       <li>' + obj.offf + '</li>
     </ul>'
    );
```

Comment: your string concatenation is wrong

Comment: Can you show how it would be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is not properly formed. It produces syntax error because the parser does not know what `> <` means. While you can use `\` like this:

```
$('.data').append(
    '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">\
        <li data-role="list-divider">' + obj.storename + '</li>\
        <li>' + obj.notes + '</li>\
        <li>' + obj.rejected + '</li>\
        <li>' + obj.offf + '</li>\
    </ul>'
);
```

But I would rather concatenate the strings using the `+` operator:

```
$('.data').append(
    '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">' +
    '<li data-role="list-divider">' + obj.storename + '</li>' +
    '<li>' + obj.notes + '</li>' +
    '<li>' + obj.rejected + '</li>' +
    '<li>' + obj.offf + '</li>' +
    '</ul>'
);
```

Comment: I never knew that, thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation

```
$('.data').append(
    '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">\
       <li data-role="list-divider">' + obj.storename + '</li>\
       <li>' + obj.notes + '</li>\
       <li>' + obj.rejected + '</li>\
       <li>' + obj.offf + '</li>\
     </ul>');
```

You can use `\` to indicate the string is continued in the next line, or use `+` as the concatenation operator

```
$('.data').append(
    '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">'
    +'<li data-role="list-divider">' + obj.storename + '</li>'
    +'<li>' + obj.notes + '</li>'
    +'<li>' + obj.rejected + '</li>'
    +'<li>' + obj.offf + '</li>'
    +'</ul>');
```